# How to set in mockmvc the custom converters

Tags: spring, kotlin, unit-testing, model-view-controller, mockmvc

I have a enum class `foobar` with the custom converter:

```kotlin
enum class FooBarEnum(
    val type: Integer,
    val code: String
) {
    FooBarAAA( 1, "AAA"),
    FooBarBBB( 2, "BBB");

    @JsonValue
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${type}:${code}"
    }

    companion object {
        fun forValue(value: String): FooBar? {
            return values().firstOrNull { it.toString() == value }
        }
    }

...

    class EnumConverter : Converter<String, FooBar> {
        override fun convert(source: String): FooBar? {
            return forValue(source)
        }
    }

...

}
```

I have a endpoint in a endpoint as:

```kotlin
@Api(tags = [SwaggerConfiguration.Tags.Foo])
@RestController
@RequestMapping(AppConstants.ApiRestBaseUrl + "/foo/{johndoeId}/bar")
class FooBarController @Autowired constructor(
    private val authService: AuthApi,
    private val foobarApi: FooBarApi
) {
    @JsonView(Bar::class)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the bar")
    @GetMapping(value = ["/{foobarenum}"], produces = [Controller.ProducesJson])
    fun getRanking(
        @PathVariable johndoeId: String,
        @PathVariable foobarenum: FooBarEnum?,
        filter: OtherFilter,
        authSession: Authentication
    ): Bar {
        if (foobarenum == null) {
            throw ApiError.NotFound(
                "Invalid foobarenum specified. Valid ones: ${
                    foobarenum.values().joinToString(", ")
                })}"
            )
        }

        val currentUser = authService.getUser(authSession)
        return this.foobarApi.getBar(currentUser, johndoeId, filter.copy(foobarenum = foobarenum))
    }

...
```

Then I have the unit test for this controller:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [ApiTestConfiguration::class, FooBarController::class])
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class FooBarControllerTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val mockMvc: MockMvc
) {

...

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("admin")
    fun `Get the bar`() {
        val johndoeId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()


        val request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            "/api/v1/foo/{johndoeId}/bar/1:AAA",
            johndoeId
        )                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

        val perform = this.mockMvc.perform(request
        )
        perform
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    }

...
```

The custom converter is registered in the webconfiguration:

```kotlin
@ComponentScan("es.happy.project.server")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("es.happy.project.server.settings")
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class WebConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {

...


    override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
        ...
        registry.addConverter(FooBarEnum.EnumConverter())
    }

}
```

But the happy mockmvc attribute uses default converter of spring and of course fail the test...and the real server uses the custom converter from the code of project and not fail.

How do I configure the unit test to use the custom converter?